# how can i add if condition image.url.present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I have here four images, what I want if one of those images are empty to not showing it as missing. here's an image to explain more [image]

```
   <% [@car.image.url, @car.image2.url, @car.image3.url, @car.image4.url].each do |image| %>
              <%= link_to "javascript:void(0)", data: { image: image, zoom_image: image } do %>
                <%= image_tag image%>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

Comment: post the output, or some semblance thereof, for `[@car.image.url, @car.image2.url, @car.image3.url, @car.image4.url]` this way we know what to check for. e.g. is `@car.image4.url` nil or an empty string or something else? Also if `@car.image4.url` is simply a broken link you will have the same issue and this will be harder to check for so we need to understand the overall output to propose a viable solution

Comment: @engineersmnky All i want if one of the images empty (no value) to not show in the list as missing

Comment: The answer proposed already provides that; however you said it does not work for you which leads me to believe something else is at play that we cannot see currently and thus my request.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple if will make it work

```
<% [@car.image.url, @car.image2.url, @car.image3.url, @car.image4.url].each do |image| %>
   <%= link_to "javascript:void(0)", data: { image: image, zoom_image: image } do %>
     <%= image_tag image%>
   <% end if image.present? %>
<% end %>
```

or, you can `compact` the array, then iterate. Like this:

```
<% [@car.image.url, @car.image2.url, @car.image3.url, @car.image4.url].select(&:present?).each do |image| %>
   <%= link_to "javascript:void(0)", data: { image: image, zoom_image: image } do %>
     <%= image_tag image%>
   <% end%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: both of them didn't work. the image still shows missing

Comment: Can you post what are `@car.image.url, @car.image2.url, @car.image3.url, @car.image4.url`?

Comment: If you have something in the url, but the url doesn't really point to an image, the same thing will happen.

Comment: these are images. I want if one of them is empty to remove it from the list. Like the picture in my question above, you can see image4 is missing, it shouldn't be anything in it's place.

Comment: @nourza what sam said is ok. What you actually want is to remove the entire img element if the image is broken. You need to define a onError event on the img.

Comment: @razvans yes thats what i want